# azure task: Copy Files@2 If no files are matched throw error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i like to fail the task if no files are matched.
from reading the [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

i can see its behavior is exactly the opposite.

here is my download and copy task, how when its 0 files to throw error and to fail the pipeline

```
steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'Artifacts'
        itemPattern: | 
                **/*.a
                **/*s.plist*
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
        Contents: | 
                **/*.a
                **/*s.plist*
        TargetFolder: '$(Agent.HomeDirectory)/../${{parameters.FolderCompile}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is only:

1. Write powershell/bash script to schek if there is eny file and if not then make `exit 1` from the script what fails the task
2. Analyze logs of your `CopyFiles` task in a similar way how it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168812/extract-files-to-process-no-files-were-found-warning/64169161#64169161)

Comment: Thank you , i did the number 1 suggestion with bash script

Comment: see if you can help with this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314830/azure-pipeline-how-detect-when-pipeline-stoped-when-script-waiting-for-user-inpu